How do I fit a paragraph on the right hand side of an item?
How do I get text in this arrangement? The lines are the margins of the page. "x = y + 1" is a line of math in a box, as wide as the text inside. The paragraph extends from the right side of the box to the page margin.
|                                                        |
| +-----------+  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur |
| | x = y + 1 |  adipiscing elit,  sed do eiusmod tempor |
| +-----------+  incididunt ut  labore  et dolore magna. |
|                Ut enim ad  minim  veniam, quis nostrud |
|                exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut    |
|                                                        |

I can get the box using \framebox. I've looked into using a table for the layout, but it seems that I have to use fixed-width columns. My text will be auto-generated, so I cannot adjust each width by hand.

Welcome to TeX SE. Have you tried tabularx? With this package, you can specify the witdh of the table and then use a X column that will use the remaining width.

The tricky bit is aligning the tops instead of the baselines.  \raisebox{-\height){...} is one solution.  Adding \hrule height0pt above each is another.

With help of the tabularray package:
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
   
    \begin{center}
\begin{tblr}{colspec={@{} Q[c, mode=math] X @{}}}
x=y+1   &  \lipsum[66]
\end{tblr}
    \end{center}
\end{document}

or with tabularx package as menitoned @Alain Remillard in his comment:
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
   
\[
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} c X @{}}
$x=y+1$   &  \lipsum[66]
\end{tabularx}
\]
\end{document}


IN both cases you will get the following result:

Ah, perfect! Thank you.
